# QnAMakerDialog - using metadata

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-qna-maker

With the qnamaker 4.0 api (and even 3.0 I think) you can send metadata to the api and use that to boost the score of answers that contain the metadata tag. I'm having trouble implementing this using the `QnAMakerDialog` in the C# SDK. Is there a simple way of doing this or do you need to create your own service/dialog to implement this?

Also, related to this, is there no way to get to the message before the `QnAMakerDialog`? Like overriding `MessageReceivedAsync` (which you can't since it's not virtual - atleast not in the version I'm using, Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices 1.1.7)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact you are using the Nuget package `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices`, available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices)

I had a look to the current sources (it's open-sourced on Github, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices)) and as you can see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMaker/QnAMakerService/QnAMakerService.cs#L92)  , this package (at least now, with 1.1.7 version) is using QnAMaker API v2 :

```
public static readonly Uri UriBaseV2 = new Uri("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases");
```

So you will not have the benefits of metadata introduced in QnAMaker API v3

Comment: Oh, right. Makes sense, and the reason it works with my 4.0 api is cause I create a QnAMakerAttribute instance and pass it to the constructor with an endpoint url specified. That made things clearer, thanks alot!